# How can I add a token to headers in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3

In the following method I am trying to send a key through headers in Ionic 3. But when I try to add a key through a variable, for example through `this.key`, then the key value is empty. However, when I send a static value in place of a key, for example `"c0sc8ggsk0kso8sggkowcsckck80ookgckkwkwgw"`, then it work perfectly. So, how can I use a variable for the key value?

```
key : any;    

getToken(){
  console.log('get token invoked')
  this.loading.show();
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.append("API-KEY", ""+this.key);
  this.http.get(this.rest.url+ 'v1/auth/getAccessToken',{headers: headers}).subscribe(data=>{         
    if(data['status']==true){
      this.loading.hide();
      console.log('token value is',data['token']);           
      this.storage.set('token',data['token']);
    }
    if(data['status']==false){
      this.loading.hide();
      console.log('token error msg ',data['message']);
    }  
  })
}
```

Comment: Try to set key like this .headers.set("Api-key",""+this.key)

Comment: Does key exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because `append` cretes new version of headers thus you must reasign it

```
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers=headers.append("API-KEY", ""+this.key);
```